# What package is required to use initial_split()?

Tags: r

I'm willing to use the initial_split() function, but whenever I type it R returns this message: No documentation for ‘initial_split’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??initial_split’.

What kind of package do I need to install?

Comment: try the rsample package - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rsample/versions/0.1.0/topics/initial_split

Comment: I've tried that too, but whenever I enter library(rsample) I get an error

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rsample’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘dplyr’ 0.8.5 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required

Comment: try `update.packages()` ?

Comment: So you need to update your version of dplyr with ```install.packages("dplyr")```

Comment: So I tried install.packages("dplyr") and then did update.packages("rsample") and entered library("rsample"), but I still gett the same error message

Comment: All good, I've fixed the problem by restarting R. Thanks anyways for your help.

Answer (score 1):

the library(tidymodels) is used to the split the data into training and testing  using the function initial_split().

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).